# Image when load in content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I load in some content to a div from an external page divs, based on select-box options. I noticed that sometimes it takes a while when loading a div containing alot of information and I wounder if there is a way to make a image-loader (gif) meanwhile the div loads?

Here is the code I am using to load the content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#select_box").change(function(){ 
    var selectedOption = $('#select_box :selected').val(); 
    $containerDiv = $('#div_where_content_loads_in'); 
            switch (selectedOption)
            {
                case "Option1":$containerDiv.load( "page.html#div1" ); break;
                case "Option2":$containerDiv.load( "page.html#div2" ); break;
                case "Option3":$containerDiv.load( "page.html#div3" ); break;
                case "Option4":$containerDiv.load( "page.html#div4" ); break;
           }
   }); 
});
```

I have seen some turtorials but think I need some help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a show and hide functions and call them with ajax.load function. But last nigh I've realised I could just listen ajaxStart and Stop events. Well It may be normal way of life for you but it never came to my mind. Anyways, here is the code to listen start/stop events and show/hide loading animation with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () { showProgress() }).ajaxStop(function () { hideProgress() });
});

function showProgress() {
    $('body').append('<div id="progress"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="" width="16" height="11" /> Loading...</div>');
    $('#progress').center();
}

function hideProgress() {
    $('#progress').remove();
}

jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.load()` accepts a second argument, a callback function, which is executed once the content finishes loading. The idea is, you show a spinner before calling `$containerDiv.load()` and hide it in the callback.

Say your html is

```
<select id="select_box">
    <option value="foo">Load content from 'page.html #foo'</option>
    <option value="bar">Load content from 'page.html #bar'</option>
    <option value="foobar">Load content from 'page.html #foobar'</option>
    <option value="barfoo">Load content from 'page.html #barfoo'</option>
</select>
```

Your javascript can be this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $containerDiv = $('#div_where_content_loads_in');
    var $spinner = $containerDiv.find('#spinner');
    $("#select_box").change(function() { // Called when user selects a value
        // Get the selected option
        // one of "foo", "bar", "foobar", "barfoo"
        var selectedOption = this.value;

        // Get the content URL
        // one of "page.html #foo", "page.html #bar",
        //        "page.html #foobar", "page.html #barfoo"
        var contentURL = "page.html #"+selectedOption;

        $spinner.show(); // Show the spinner before starting content load

        // Now that contentURL is the correct URL we want to load, call $.load
        $containerDiv.load( contentURL, function() {
            $spinner.hide(); // Hide the spinner when the content finished loading
        });
    });
});
```

Notice that the `switch` statement has also been avoided. This assumes that your container contains an element with id `spinner`, properly styled with CSS and containing a spinner gif.

Comment: If I get this then this should just be written above the already existing code and not in any existing tag in code?

Comment: This can replace the code you provided in the question. The only requirement is you also alter your HTML to include a "spinner" element inside your container in which you load the content. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Ok! But where to put the links in the code? (Beginner at java)

Comment: The code sample can be placed in a `<script></script>` tag in your HTML, or, alternatively, put in a separate `main.js` file and loaded like `<script src="main.js"></script>`. In either case, the `<script>` tag should be placed in the `<head>` of your HTML document. Still not sure if I am answering your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. I mean the links in the select-menu (case "Option1":$containerDiv.load( "page.html#div1" ); break; etc)
, if I just replace the code with your code, where is the links?

Comment: The select-menu markup should not have to change. In the code you provided, you are running a `switch` statement over the selected option value (Option1, Option2, etc...) and then loading the corresponding content (page.html#div1, page.html#div2, etc...). I removed the `switch` by extracting the last character of the selected option ('1', '2', '3', '4') with `selectedOption.slice(-1)` and appending it to the string `page.html#div`, to produce the needed links.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21435/discussion-between-igorraush-and-wobot)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajaxStart function for this and a .load success function callback,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#select_box").change(function(){ 

     $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
       $('.loader').show();
     });

    var selectedOption = $('#select_box :selected').val(); 
    $containerDiv = $('#div_where_content_loads_in'); 
            switch (selectedOption)
            {
                case "Option1":
                    $containerDiv.load( "page.html#div1", function(){
                       $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
                    }); 
                    break;
                case "Option2":
                    $containerDiv.load( "page.html#div2", function(){
                       $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
                    });  
                    break;
                case "Option3":
                    $containerDiv.load( "page.html#div3", function(){
                       $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
                    });  
                    break;
                case "Option4":
                    $containerDiv.load( "page.html#div4", function(){
                       $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
                    });  
                    break;
           }
   }); 
});
```

try this and see if helps.

Comment: I tried that and dident work. I made a class .loader with a background image I guess that what correct?